# Jade(PUG) to Handlebars, Helper function for loading SVG image Issue

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, pug

I am converting a pug project to handlebars.

The problem is, it loads markup text instead of the image. But this works fine with pug(jade).

I wrote the helper function inside my helper.js file as follows.

```
const fs = require('fs');
exports.icon = (name) => fs.readFileSync(`./public/images/icons/${name}.svg`);
```

I am calling this function inside main.hbs file

```
 {{icon 'logo'}}
```

How to solve this problem and render the image to the DOM instead of markup text?

[image: SVG Markup instead of Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "triple-stash" `{{{icon 'logo'}}}`. See https://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping